# Truffle: provide a different config file name via the CLI?

Tags: truffle, truffle-config

I've read through the Truffle [docs](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration) on configuration, but I haven't found the option of providing a different file name other than `truffle-config.js` or `truffle.js`.

In my case, I need multiple files because I have different compiler settings when running coverage on my smart contracts.

Is there something I missed or this is not an available feature as of now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--config path/to/config.js` option is now implemented

Answer (score 2):

This is tracked by Truffle issue [#1879](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/1879).

(Not entirely sure what the code flow would be after its implementation, but [`getTruffleConfig.js`](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/faca82e1973bf408ed1eb9af698eaaf540ec0b32/packages/truffle-solidity-loader/lib/getTruffleConfig.js#L5) might be a good place to start having a poke around if you're feeling brave.)